# $M = \max (X,Y)$ with $X$, $Y$ independent uniform variables over $[0,1]$. Find CDF of $M$ and $E[M]$

Tags: probability

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are independent uniform $[0,1]$ random variables. Find the CDF
$F(x)$ for the random variable $M = \max(X,Y)$ and find $E[M]$.

So $M$ will be uniform over $[0,1]$ and is the probability of $(0 < M < k)$ the probability that $(0 < X < k) + (0 < Y < k)$? I am not even sure if I should assume these variables are discrete or continuous..

Would the cumulative distribution function be:

$0$ when $M < 0$

$2M/1$ when $0 < M < 1$

$1$ when $M \geq 1$

and would $E[M]$ simply be $E[X] = E[Y] = 1/2$?

I have a feeling something is going over my head here. Is what I am doing correct?

Thank you!

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/495958/maximum-of-two-uniform-distributions

Answer (score 1):

no $E(M) \ne 1/2$.

You need to find
$P(\max(X,Y) \le m)$. When is max of two numbers less than a given value?