# X and Y are uniformly distributed independent random variables, let Z = max{X,Y}. find the PDF of Z

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have a few questions regarding this problem that I do not quite understand.

For a random variable U distributed uniformly on the interval [0,1] its CDF is given by

$$\ F_U(u) = \begin{Bmatrix} 0, & u < 0 \\ u, & 0 \le u \le 1, \\ 1, & u > 1 \\ \end{Bmatrix} $$

1. I don't understand why for values of u > 1 the CDF of U is 1. I would think that $\ F_U $ would be undefined outside of the interval that the random variable U is defined on.

====The solution to the problem in post title and  explanation of my lack of understanding====

Let Z = max{X,Y}. For z$\ \in $ (0,1)

$\ F_Z(z) = P(Z \le z ) $

=  P(X$\le$z and Y$\le$z)
= $\ F_X(z)F_Y(z)$
= $\ z^2 $

2. I understand that the CDF of a u.r.v. is $\ \frac{x-a}{b-a}$ for X on [a,b] so that $\ F_X(z)$ and $\ F_Y(z) $ are equal to z, but I do not understand why P(X$\le$z and Y$\le$z) = $\ F_Z$

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ has to be smaller or equal to $z$ if $max(x,y)=z$. Try out some values for $x$ and $y$. //  $x,y$ cannot be greater than $z$.

Comment: The PDF of $Z=\max(X,Y)$ is the derivative of the CDF, which is asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/783739/m-maxx-y-with-x-y-independent-uniform-variables-over-0-1-find-cdf-of-m-a). An answer is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/495958/maximum-of-two-uniform-distributions).

Answer (score 2):

> I don't understand why for values of $u > 1$ the CDF of $U$ is $1$. I would think that $F_U$ would be undefined outside of the interval that the random variable $U$ is defined on.

The probability density function *is* defined for values above the support's supremum; it equals zero there.   (Likewise for values below the infimum.)

$U$ has a support of $(0;1)$, so $\mathsf P(U\leqslant 1)=1$ by the Law of total probability.   A random variable is *certainly* not-more than the supremum of its support.   Likewise it will also certainly not be greater than any higher value.   $\therefore~\forall u\geqslant 1 : \mathsf P(U\leqslant u)= 1~$.

> I do not understand why $P(X\leqslant z\text{ and }Y\leqslant z) =
> F_Z(z)$

Because $F_Z(z)=\mathsf P(Z\leqslant z)$, by definition, and $Z=\max\{X,Y\}$.

Now when $Z$ is *not greater than* $z$, neither $X$ nor $Y$ is greater than $z$, and *vice versa*.   Thus the event $\{Z\leq z\}$ is the join of the events $\{X\leqslant z\}$ and $\{Y\leqslant z\}$.

$$\begin{align}F_Z(z) &= \mathsf P(Z\leqslant z) \\ & =\mathsf P(\min\{X,Y\}\leqslant z) \\ &= \mathsf P(X\leqslant z~\cap~ Y\leqslant z) \\ &= \mathsf P(X\leqslant z)~\mathsf P(Y\leqslant z) \\ &= F_X(z)~F_Y(z)\end{align}$$