# Find the distributions of $X$ and $Y$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $A$ and $B$ be two i.i.d. uniform random variables in $[0,1]$.

(a) Determine the distributions of $2 A$ and $A+B$.

(b) Let $X=\min (A, B)$ and $Y=\max (A, B)$.

1. Find the distributions of $X$ and $Y$.
2. Show that the pair $(X, Y)$ has a density and compute it.

---

I have tried,

Since $A,B\sim U(0,1)$
We got the pdf $f(x)=1 $ for $0\leq x\leq 1$
Then I can use transformation of distribution to find the the distribution of $2A, A+B$
Like finding Jacobian.
Am I right to this question? For the next question I have think many times. But I cannot. Please kindly show me how to do this. Thank in advance!

Comment: For maximum, see [Related Q & A](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/495958/maximum-of-two-uniform-distributions?rq=1) from margin of this page.

Answer (score 1):

Comments and clues from simulation.

For a million iterations of a random variable, the sample mean and standard deviation should approximate population mean and SD to about two or three places.

```
set.seed(2021)
a = runif(10^6);  b = runif(10^6)  # indep std unif

v = 2*a
summary(v); sd(v)
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
0.0000029 0.5011825 0.9995353 1.0004032 1.4997764 1.9999995 
[1] 0.5772774  # standard deviation

w = a + b
summary(w); sd(w)
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
0.002293 0.707178 0.999928 1.000027 1.291958 1.999021 
[1] 0.4080204

x = pmin(a,b)
summary(x); sd(x)
 Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
0.0000014 0.1337490 0.2926047 0.3331254 0.4994293 0.9994519 
[1] 0.235804

y = pmax(a,b)
summary(y); sd(y)
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
0.001617 0.500199 0.706913 0.666902 0.866216 1.000000 
[1] 0.2354649
```

Histograms of the four simulated distributions:

[image]

R code for figure:

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
 hist(v, prob=T, br=30, col="skyblue2")
 hist(w, prob=T, br=30, col="skyblue2")
 hist(x, prob=T, br=40, col="skyblue2")
  curve(dbeta(x,1,2), add=T, col="orange", lwd=3)
 hist(y, prob=T, br=40, col="skyblue2")
  curve(dbeta(x,2,1), add=T, col="orange", lwd=2)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

Plot suggesting the joint distribution of $(X,Y),$ using only 10,000 points for clarity.

```
X = x[1:10000]; Y = y[1:10000]
plot(X,Y, pch=".")
```

[image]

The min and max have beta distributions. You can use the CDF method for those. Also, see 'order statistics' in a math stat book for distributions of smallest and largest order statistics (min and max, respectively.)

For the derivation of the minimum of $A$ and $B,$ perhaps start with:

$$1 - F_X(x) = P(X > x) = P(A > x, B > x)\\
= P(A > x)P(B > x) = (1-x)^2,$$

for $0 < x < 1.$